# Creating columns for a range of dates in a loop

Tags: r

[Actual Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0ksm.png)I have loop that runs fine that sums the amount of a column based on the range of some dates. This loop is as follows:

```
 Sd <- as.Date('2017-01-01',tz = "GMT")
 EndDate <- as.Date('2017-01-20',tz = "GMT")
 Ed <- EndDate + 10


 while (Sd < Ed) {


 Sd <- Sd + 1
 LTV1 <- LTV %>% group_by(InstallationDate)%>% filter(z < Sd) %>% 
 summarize(Amount = sum(USAmount))


   }
 mn <-   as.data.frame(LTV1)
```

In the above, Z is a column containing dates.
Now i want to create a column for each day that the above loop runs, with each column indicating the amount collected that particular day. So in this case we would need 30 columns.

I have tried creating another loop that will be creating a column for each day, but it does nothing, and the output is still the same. Code is as follows:

```
  Sd <- as.Date('2017-01-01',tz = "GMT")
  EndDate <- as.Date('2017-01-20',tz = "GMT")
  Ed <- EndDate + 10

  V <- Ed - Sd  

  for(i in 1:V){


  mn[ , paste0("Amount", i)] <-   while (Sd < Ed) {


  Sd <- Sd + 1
  LTV1 <- LTV %>% group_by(InstallationDate)%>% filter(z < Sd) %>% 
  summarize(Amount = sum(USAmount))

 }

 }

 mn <-   as.data.frame(LTV1)
```

This does not work at all, although it runs. I am not sure what i am doing wrong or what the fix is. 
I would be grateful for any feedback since i am quit stuck.
Desirable outcome will be:

```
 InstallationDate     Amount1   Amount2  Amount3 ...........Amount30
 2017-01-01             
 2017-01-02             
     .
     . 
     .
```

Comment: Please don't keep posting the same question, again and again. Edit your previous questions for clarity. As I asked on your last post, **please** post  a few rows of actual sample ouput for your sample input, that will make it make sense.

Comment: Hi Gregor, i have posted the output when you run the code for 10 days. Now i have the summed amount after 10 days. However i would like for each day to be summed  cumulatively, in separate columns. So i would need an extra 9 columns. The 10th column should much the column "Amount" in the screenshot i have posted.

Comment: Please comment and edit your previous question that is still open,